# Centos 6 Install PHP 5.6 Memcached conflicts

Tags: centos

I have tried to install PHP Memcached but got error `conflicts between attempted installs of`

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum --enablerepo=remi-php56 install php-pecl-memcached
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, replace, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos-hn.viettelidc.com.vn
 * epel: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * extras: centos-hn.viettelidc.com.vn
 * remi-php56: mirror.23media.de
 * remi-safe: mirror.23media.de
 * updates: centos-hn.viettelidc.com.vn
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pecl-memcached.x86_64 0:2.2.0-3.el6.remi.5.6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-pecl-msgpack(x86-64) for package: php-pecl-memcached-2.2.0-3.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-pecl-igbinary(x86-64) for package: php-pecl-memcached-2.2.0-3.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmemcachedutil.so.2()(64bit) for package: php-pecl-memcached-2.2.0-3.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmemcachedprotocol.so.0()(64bit) for package: php-pecl-memcached-2.2.0-3.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmemcached.so.11()(64bit) for package: php-pecl-memcached-2.2.0-3.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libmemcached-last-libs.x86_64 0:1.0.18-6.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package libmemcached10.x86_64 0:1.0.16-1.ius.el6 will be installed
---> Package php-pecl-igbinary.x86_64 0:1.2.1-1.el6.remi.5.6 will be installed
---> Package php-pecl-msgpack.x86_64 0:0.5.7-1.el6.remi.5.6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

======================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                        Arch                           Version                                       Repository                          Size
======================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 php-pecl-memcached                             x86_64                         2.2.0-3.el6.remi.5.6                          remi-php56                         101 k
Installing for dependencies:
 libmemcached-last-libs                         x86_64                         1.0.18-6.el6.remi                             remi-safe                          119 k
 libmemcached10                                 x86_64                         1.0.16-1.ius.el6                              webtatic                           154 k
 php-pecl-igbinary                              x86_64                         1.2.1-1.el6.remi.5.6                          remi-php56                          38 k
 php-pecl-msgpack                               x86_64                         0.5.7-1.el6.remi.5.6                          remi-php56                          54 k

Transaction Summary
======================================================================================================================================================================
Install       5 Package(s)

Total size: 467 k
Total download size: 273 k
Installed size: 1.4 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/2): libmemcached-last-libs-1.0.18-6.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm                                                                                     | 119 kB     00:00
(2/2): libmemcached10-1.0.16-1.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                                              | 154 kB     00:01
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                                  47 kB/s | 273 kB     00:05
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib64/libhashkit.so.2.0.0 conflicts between attempted installs of libmemcached-last-libs-1.0.18-6.el6.remi.x86_64 and libmemcached10-1.0.16-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libmemcached.so.11.0.0 conflicts between attempted installs of libmemcached-last-libs-1.0.18-6.el6.remi.x86_64 and libmemcached10-1.0.16-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libmemcachedutil.so.2.0.0 conflicts between attempted installs of libmemcached-last-libs-1.0.18-6.el6.remi.x86_64 and libmemcached10-1.0.16-1.ius.el6.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Fear not! Just install the package libmemcached-last first. This may not get selected automatically if another repo has installed libmemcached. Once installed just run your initial yum install command again and enjoy.